# How to write an update query using joins and the arithmetic operator

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I Have two tables. The first is prodstock, and the second is orderDetails: follows:

1. prodstock table

   [image]
2. OrderDetails Table

   [image]

When I change the status of the order table and deliver, the quantity in my product table should decrease by the quantity in the order table, but I have no idea how to construct a query that does that.

Comment: I would use two statements that are in a transaction.

Comment: Please show us your query ?

Comment: If you are allowed to, I would use a trigger, so that the DB engine enforces it.  The trigger would be on the order table after update and it will reduce the quantity in the product table.

Comment: @RohitGupta can you tell me how can i do this??

Comment: @h.m.i.13 Agreed. Some people are tempted to use a trigger, but transactions really are better at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this query which works for me:

```sql
UPDATE prodstock 
INNER JOIN orderdetails ON prodstock.cat_id = orderdetails.cat_id AND
           prodstock.dyenumber = orderdetails.dyenumber 
SET prodstock.total_stock = prodstock.total_stock - orderdetails.qty
WHERE orderdetails.order_id = 2;
```

Comment: Your post said "thanks for the help"... who helped you and where? Is this code based on someone else's code somewhere?

Comment: @TylerH It is not based on someone else's code, and I posted it to help others.